# Linear transformation problem to prove equality of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $S$, $T : V \to W$ are linear
transformations, such that $\ker(T) = \ker(S)$ and $\mbox{im}(T) = \mbox{im}(S)$. Is
$S = T$?

Answer (score 2):

No, let $T$ be any linear transform, and $S=aT$, with $a\neq 1$ a constant, and you got *one* counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

For an easy counterexample, take $T:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\quad x\mapsto x$ and $S:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\quad x\mapsto -x$.